# Android Studio says FAILURE: Build failed with an exception after updating to 3.6.2

Tags: android-studio, gradle

**All my codes was running fine. But When I updated the android studio to 3.6.2 it show:**

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project /home/AK_47/AndroidStudioProjects/MyProject

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.2-6040484.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.2-6040484 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.2-6040484 available for offline mode.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
5 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 4 up-to-date
```

I was trying to make an ANDROID application. But after updating it isn't working. Any solution?

Comment: Please make sure you are connnected to the internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that the dependency can't be downloaded because you are in offline mode or  have an active Internet connection is not available. 
Steps to try

1. Try to turn Off Gradle's offline mode. You are turn off by

```
View > Tool Windows > Gradle
```

from the menu bar.Here On the top of the Gradle window ,click on Toggle Offline Mode button in the Gradle window.[image: You can refer below image]

2. Check the internet connection and build again.

Hope this answer will help...

Answer (score 2):

Try to turn off Gradle Offline mode from Gradle tool located at right side of Android Studio.
then please follow below steps:

Run following command to clear gradle cache:

```
 rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/
```

after that please click on `Invalidate Caches/Restart` from File menu then further processing will happen which dowloads all the libraries again so it takes time but also resolves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

At Gradle I used
`rm -rf ~/.gradle/`
Then `gradle clean build`
And `./gradlew test`