# Gradle Build Failed - 3.6.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have not been able to build gradle after installing Android Studio. I have not written any codes for the app and yet the build is failing.

Please help me

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.diceout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Field to hold the score
    int score;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Set inital score
        score = 0;

        //Create greeting
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Welcome to DiceOut",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

### build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.diceout"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

### build.gradle(DiceOut)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {


    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        // OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.6, 0.99.99]'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter ()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

### Gradle Error

Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\lzi7\AndroidStudioProjects\DiceOut

Gradle Daemon started in 10 s 133 ms

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build completed with 4 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Cannot isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@1fd0552a of artifact transform AarResourcesCompilerTransform

  > Could not isolate value com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@1fd0552a of type AarResourcesCompilerTransform.Parameters
  >   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
  >   Could not download aapt2-3.6.1-6040484-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.1-6040484): No cached version available for offline mode
- Try:

  ## Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Cannot isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@1fd0552a of artifact transform AarResourcesCompilerTransform

  > Could not isolate value com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@1fd0552a of type AarResourcesCompilerTransform.Parameters
  >   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
  >   Could not download aapt2-3.6.1-6040484-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.1-6040484): No cached version available for offline mode
- Try:

  ## Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

### 3: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Cannot isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@1fd0552a of artifact transform AarResourcesCompilerTransform

  > Could not isolate value com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@1fd0552a of type AarResourcesCompilerTransform.Parameters
  >   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
  >   Could not download aapt2-3.6.1-6040484-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.1-6040484): No cached version available for offline mode
- Try:

  ## Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

### 4: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Cannot isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@1fd0552a of artifact transform AarResourcesCompilerTransform

  > Could not isolate value com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@1fd0552a of type AarResourcesCompilerTransform.Parameters
  >   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
  >   Could not download aapt2-3.6.1-6040484-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.1-6040484): No cached version available for offline mode
- Try:

  ## Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 41s
2 actionable tasks: 2 up-to-date

Comment: Probably update your gradle version

Comment: Connect your development tool with internet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61209444/android-studio-says-failure-build-failed-with-an-exception-after-updating-to-3/61211245#61211245 see if this will help you