# Android studio compilation error from kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, kotlin-android-extensions, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I tried compiling android but it gives me the following error

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
       > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.3-6040484.
         Required by:
             project :app
          > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.3-6040484 available for offline mode.
          > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.3-6040484 available for offline mode.

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I saw this web page https://discuss.gradle.org/t/cached-version-error/35754
It says I should increase kotlin version but when I went into the build.gradle of my app, I did not see any kotlin in it. This is the build.gradle of my app

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61209444/android-studio-says-failure-build-failed-with-an-exception-after-updating-to-3/61211245#61211245 see if this helps you

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your issue is related to kotlin version. Looks like either you don't have a proper internet connection and your project its failing to download build tools 3.6.3 or you have "offline mode" enabled for gradle plugin. 
If you are sure you have a proper internet connection, check if you have offline mode enabled in 
Android Studio File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle

Or the quickest by just typing offline mode in the Android studio actions.

- Hit `shift + cmnd + a` in Mac or `shift + cntrl + a` in windows.
- Then type "offline mode"
- Disable it
- Sync gradle and run your proyect again.

This should solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you I found a solution to it. Sorry for the really late response