# Design editor is unavailable until a successful build error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When I start Android Studio, there is only message displaying:

Error:-

> Gradle Daemon started in 19 s 772 ms
>
> CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL in 4m 6s

It shows Configure Successful but Build is continue processing

[image: screenshot]

Also shows this error:-

> 11:58 Gradle sync started
>
> 12:03 Gradle sync failed: While loading class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.ContextKt: Invalid code attribute name index 964 in class file kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/load/java/lazy/ContextKt [Plugin: org.jetbrains.kotlin] (5 m 5 s 611 ms)

Comment: Please reffer this answer from second steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/61651738/12386821

Comment: I try this but nothing happened

Comment: Please reffer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61227243/12386821 and if it usefull then please upvote so other user can get benefit from it