# Exception android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/selector_tab_blue_white.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0601d8

Tags: android, material-design, android-resources, android-tablayout, android-vectordrawable

I am using tabLayout as

```
  <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabLayoutSubscriptionDays"
                    style="@style/CustomTabLayoutTextSizeSix"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    app:tabBackground="@color/selector_tab_blue_white"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/transparent"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/black" />
```

In some devices i am getting exception as like : android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/selector_tab_blue_white.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0601d8

This is my selector which is in color directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@color/blue_4880ff" android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:color="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

I have tried so many solutions regarding this like:

```
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}

AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)
```

These solutions I have tried.

If anyone can help then it will be so good. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The `app:tabBackground` attribute requires a **reference** meaning it must be to a drawable resource.

```
    <!-- Reference to a background to be applied to tabs. -->
    <attr format="reference" name="tabBackground"/>
```

You will want to create a drawable with a shape that references the desired color (in this case, `color/selector_tab_blue_white.xml`).

For example, `drawable/selector_tab_blue_white_background.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/selector_tab_blue_white" />
</shape>
```

In your layout xml change the `app:tabBackground` reference attribute to:

```
   app:tabBackground="@drawable/selector_tab_blue_white_background"
```

This worked for me even when the desired color `color/selector_tab_blue_white.xml` is a color selector.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add that drawable file in 2 folders along with drawable folder:

```
drawable
drawable-v24
```

Then it will not crash on any device.

Hope this helps

Comment: My Selector is in color directory.

Comment: why is it in color directory? can you try moving to drawable and try

Comment: Because it's color selector so it's there and yes i tried moving it into drawable.

Answer (score 0):

Please Follow below steps to resolve this issue ..

1. first check this file is present in project or not
2. now sync your gradle
3. Click on clean project
4. Click on Rebuild project
5. Invalidate Caches/Restart
6. Re-run project

Comment: I did everything what you described and if it's not there then how i have given you .XML file ?

Comment: Please move your selector XMl into drawable folder then change app:tabBackground="@color/selector_tab_blue_white" into app:tabBackground="@drawable/selector_tab_blue_white"

Answer (score 0):

In declare-styleable of TabLayout

`<attr format="reference" name="tabBackground"/>`

So in your case, modify the following

`<item android:color="@color/blue_4880ff" android:state_selected="true" /> <item android:color="@color/white" />`

into

`<item android:drawable="@color/blue_4880ff" android:state_selected="true" /> <item android:drawable="@color/white" />`